# Material ui autocomplete multiple search, different input order

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm a bit in trouble to manage multiple search in different order with mui autocomplete v4.x.x.

My mysql query is ok and send back the list of results I want but nothin is displayed on the autocomplete screen options.

If I search this => "Jules Ferry as", I got the result because of "Jules Ferry" is the name, and "as" is the beginning of the city.
If I try to replace the city by zipcode it doesn't works.

What I tried is to invert the result of the getOptionLabel function and it works now for the zipcode but not for the city....

My question is, is it possible to get results with multiple words in different order with mui autocomplete ?

Here is my code :

```
    const getOptionLabel = (option) => {
    if (option) {
      return `${option.nom} ${option.ville} ${option.code_postal}`;
    }
    return "";
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
        onChange={handleValueChange}
        value={autocompleteValue}
        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => {              
          return (
            option.nom === value.nom &&
            option.ville === value.ville &&
            option.code_postal &&
            value.code_postal
          );
        }}
        className="organizationAutocomplete"
        options={organizationsListOptions}
        disableListWrap
        onInputChange={handleGetData}
        disabled={dispensed == 1}
        filterOptions={filterOptions}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => getOptionLabel(option)}
        renderOption={(props) => {
          return isInspecteur ? (
            <ul>
              <li {...props}>{props.academie}</li>
            </ul>
          ) : (
            <ul>
              <li {...props}>
                {props.nom} - {props.ville} - {props.code_postal}
              </li>
            </ul>
          );
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, disableUnderline: true }}
            label={
              isInspecteur
                ? "Exemples: Aix-Marseille, Lille, Toulouse"
                : "Exemple: Jules Ferry, Jean Moulin, 76350"
            }
          />
        )}
      />
```

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1):

For people how are in trouble with Mui autocomplete filter:

I already filtered my data with the back-end, so the filter from the autocomplete component is useless/ can create side effect.

And the filter is working until you specify that it should not by:

```
filterOptions={(options) => options}
```

And everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

@De_Jr is right, I was expecting MUI to keep the order from the `options` input.

Since my filtering is done by MUI (in opposite to @De_Jr's case), here how I make muiFiltering+sorting:

```
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
const filter = createFilterOptions<YourType>();
        
...

filterOptions={(options, params) => {
    let filtered = filter(options, params);

    // Sort a new time
    filtered.sort(...)

    return filtered;
})
```